# How to sort JPA entities using TreeSet

Tags: sorting, jakarta-ee, jpa, set, ejb-3.0

I have a few entity beans with sets of other entities as attributes. I want to sort them and guarantee that at every insertion they will remain sorted.
I tried this way:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Document")
public class Document implements Serializable, Comparable<Document> {

    ...

    @ManyToOne
    private Project relativeProject;

    ...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Document d) {
        long data1 = getDate().getTimeInMillis();
        long data2 = d.getDate().getTimeInMillis();
        if(data1 > data2)
            return 1;
        else
            if(data2 < data1)
                return -1;
            else
                return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object d) {
        return (getIdDocument() == ((Document)d).getIdDocument());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Long.valueOf(getIdDocument()).hashCode();
    }

}




@Entity
@Table(name="Project")
public class Project implements Serializable, Comparable<Project> {

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="relativeProject", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Sort(type = SortType.NATURAL)
    private SortedSet<Document> formedByDocuments;

    public Progetto() {
        this.formedByDocuments = new TreeSet<Document>();
    }

    ...

}
```

But it does not work. The problem is that, even if in the database there are all needed entries, when a session bean returns a `Project` there will miss some `Document`. Moreover, entries are not sorted at all in the database.

If I do not sort at all (using `HashSet`) and republish the project, everything works fine and I get all the elements in a set (but not sorted, of course).

Can someone help me to find out what's wrong with my sorting?

Comment: A small remark, but you might want to use English names in your code. This makes it much easier to share your code with others (for instance here). When I read things like 'progettoRelativo' it's like you obfuscated the code. You might as well put "jkgdklgflkg" there. I guess many others feel the same way and this might lower your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: Sorry, I know. I thought it was still clear (Documento -> Document, Progetto -> Project) but I did not think there were also more complex words.

Comment: Please post your equals() and hashCode() method for Document as well

Comment: @Andre Done. I did `hashCode()` right now, I did not implemented it before. Still not working anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming getIdDocument() returns an object and not a primitive.

In that case, you need to use equals and not ==

```
public boolean equals(Object d) {
    return (getIdDocument().equals((Document)d).getIdDocument());
}
```

**Edit:**

Looks like the problem is in the second `if(data2 < data1)` statement of the compareTo() method. This should be `if(data1 < data2)`

Comment: It is a `long` type, so `==` is fine. Anyway, I solved writing: `if(data1 > data2) return 1; else return -1;` in `compareTo()`.
But I don't understand why.

Comment: What if you simplify your compareTo()?

`return getDate().compareTo(d.getDate());`

Comment: Still working. Yet I don't understanding why my "manual" comparison between two dates didn't work.

Comment: @Simon, the second `if` was swapped around. See edited answer.